# No data is being written from Android to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to android. I am not getting where I am going wrong during debugging. I am able to see the entered fields values but in firebase(backend) the data is not updating.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAddress;
    private TextView textViewPersons;
    private Button buttonSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

        textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
                //Creating firebase object
                Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

                //Getting values to store
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating Person object
                Person person = new Person();

                //Adding values
                person.setName(name);
                person.setAddress(address);

                //Storing values to firebase
                ref.child("Person").setValue(person);


                //Value event listener for realtime data update
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //Getting the data from snapshot
                            Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                            //Adding it to a string
                            String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                            //Displaying it on textview
                            textViewPersons.setText(string);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: post your log to help finding error

Comment: You might not have permission to write the data. To detect this, add a completion listener to your calls to `setValue()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201611181313215541025

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the code by replacing

```
Person person = new Person();
        //Adding values
        person.setName(name);
        person.setAddress(address);
        //Storing values to firebase
        ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
```

with

```
ref.child("Person").setValue(name)
```